# Is my VS Code bugging or is something wrong with my code?

Tags: python, variables

I've used the return keyword to end the function, and made sure that the variable (randnum1) is in the correct scope, yet Pylance says that the variable still isn't defined. How do I fix this? (code below)

````
        def genrand1():
            randnum1 = random.randrange(rand1a, rand1b)
            return randnum1

        rand1prompt = input("The random number will be " + randnum1 + ". Is this okay? (Type yes or no")
        if rand1prompt := "yes":
            print("Okay, the number's set.")
            num1 = randnum1
        elif rand1prompt := "no":
            print("Okay. Generating a new random number...")
            genrand1()
        else:    
            print("Whoops. Something went wrong. Please type yes or no.")```
````

Comment: Hard to say without full code but I'm gonna assume `randnum1` is defined only withing a scope of function you return it from. Outside of this function this name means nothing and that's why you are getting undefined error. Return is not enough to make the variable name visible outside the function, it only gives value to the function call.

Comment: The `return` keyword is outside any function in the snippet. Can u add the function too to the snippet.

Comment: `randnum1` is a local variable of the `genrand1` function

Answer (score 1):

The `randnum1` in your input statement is not defined as it has not been defined globally. `randnum1` is a local variable as it has only been defined in the `genrand1()` function so it's only accessible within the `genrand1()` function.

To define `randnum1` globally, store the return value of the function in it: `randnum1 = genrand1()`. Like:

```
def genrand1():
    randnum1 = random.randrange(rand1a, rand1b)
    return randnum1

randnum1 = genrand1() #Stored here

rand1prompt = input("The random number will be " + randnum1 + ". Is this okay? (Type yes or no")
if rand1prompt := "yes":
    print("Okay, the number's set.")
    num1 = randnum1
elif rand1prompt := "no":
    print("Okay. Generating a new random number...")
    genrand1()
else:    
    print("Whoops. Something went wrong. Please type yes or no.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to replace the `randnum1's` from the third line with the function that returns it. 
I presume you are returning it from one function and using the same variable outside the function. 
Instead you would want to store the return value of the function in a variable and use that variable in place of randnum1. 
For example:- If you want to use the randnum1 the something like

```py
randnum1 = function()
```

Replace function with your function name. 
This is just my initial guess and getting a look on the full code will definitely be more insightful.